# Error when deploying web app (web sites) on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I don't seem to be able to deploy a website to a resource group that's already set up. I get an error that says "Deployment to resource group [Group] failed".

The detailed message is:

```
OPERATIONNAME Update hosting plan
STATUS 
EVENTTIMESTAMP Wed Mar 25 2015 18:06:59 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
CALLER [MY EMAIL]
RESOURCEURI /subscriptions/a97fdf0e-0b01-45e7-9ce1-87588ff52195/resourcegroups/[Group]/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/[Name]
SUBSCRIPTIONID a97fdf0e-0b01-45e7-9ce1-87588ff52195
EVENTSUBMISSIONTIMESTAMP Wed Mar 25 2015 18:07:20 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time)
OPERATIONID 1ec17586-8fb1-44f6-b496-5add273399ce
SUBSTATUS Not Found (HTTP Status Code: 404)
CORRELATIONID 4b1e3dd1-abc7-4760-914e-4b65cf779b7d
DESCRIPTION 
LEVEL Error
RESOURCEGROUP [Group]
RESOURCEPROVIDER Azure Web Sites
EVENTSOURCE Microsoft Resources
PROPERTIES 
statusCode:NotFound
statusMessage:{"Code":"NotFound","Message":"Cannot find HostingEnvironment with name .","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Cannot find HostingEnvironment with name ."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"NotFound","Message":"Cannot find HostingEnvironment with name .","ExtendedCode":"51004","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.","Parameters":["HostingEnvironment",""],"InnerErrors":null}}],"Innererror":null}
```

If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This eventually solved itself.